# Can you set different text colors for different "list levels" in Word 2007?

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2007

How do you make a list style that causes the text at various list nesting levels to show up in a particular color?

I assume it's in the multi-level list tool options, but cant seem to make it work.  (Just the bullets/numbers are getting colored.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Format each level the way you want it, with whatever fonts, colors, etc. you wish. Only do it once for each style that you need to use.
2. For each level, highlight the line, right-click, and select `Styles > Save Selection as New Quick Style`.

   [image: save as new quick style]
3. Look under `Define new list style` in the multilevel list dropdown on the paragraphs section of the main ribon panel. You will see that your chosen formats are now set as the format for that list level. If they are not, you can click on the dropdown for `Link level to style`, and that will make the change for you. Creating new entries in the list of that level should retain the formatting. You can then save that formatting for reuse in other lists in the future.

   [image: select level formatting]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

home > Paragraph > multilevel list > Define new List Style.

Select the level which you want to format. (You can apply to all.)

Click format at the bottom left corner and select font. There will be a menu for selecting the font color.

After your first formatting change, you can simply edit the list style you just created to specify formatting for different levels.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did, but it only affects the "number", not the actual text.

Comment: I'm on a linux laptop at the moment so I can't test it, but when I wrote the answer I was on a PC running Windows XP and Office 07. I saw three menus, one for bullet color, one for underline color, and one for font color. All worked as intended. (IIRC the font color was the left-most one.)