# Different line spacing between different list levels

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Following [this](https://superuser.com/a/252555/315715) advice, I've created a style for each of my list levels and am now modifying the styles in order to get the list looking how I'd like.

I want a large space between each level 1 item (and separating the list from the body text above and below), and a smaller space between a level 1 item and any associated level 2 items.

The desired list would look like this:

[image: List levels - subitems closer to item]

I can get very close to this by setting the "before" spacing on level 1:

[image: Level1 paragraph settings]

and the "after" spacing on level 2:

[image: Level2 paragraph settings]

But this leaves me with no space at the end of the list before the body text.

Comment: No space at the end of the list and before the body text because this space is controlled in the spacing `After` in level 1 style, not level 2. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint: For all your styles, either you set the spacing before OR the spacing after. Don't bother yourself with setting some styles with the spacing after and other styles with the spacing before because you'll eventually mix everything up.
[image: clean]

I replicate your problem and according to the following settings

**For level 1 style:**

1. `12` pt spacing before;
2. `0` pt spacing after; and
3. un-tick `Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style`.

**For level 2 style:**

1. `2` pt spacing before;
2. `0` pt spacing after; and
3. un-tick `Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style`.

**For Normal style:**

1. `12` pt spacing before (corresponding to the same amount in level 1);
2. `0` pt spacing after; and
3. un-tick `Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style`.

[image: sample]

You can change the spacing before if you find it big. You can have a special style that applies only on the texts before AND after the list if your document gained unnecessary spaces. The point here is that you don't mix the spacing in your styles :)

Comment: This is perfect: exactly what I need and no dodgy "special styles" required. *And* I learned an important thing about styles.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check the `Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style` checkbox for the Level 2 style, otherwise you'll get 12pt spacing after each level 2 paragraph.

For the body text, I would suggest these two options:

1. Edit the body style (called `Normal` if you haven't changed the defaults). Set the "Before" spacing to the desired space and check the `Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style` checkbox.

   As you mentioned in the comments after I posted only option 1 above, option 1 will increase the spacing before normal text in other places in the document, in first occurrences of the Normal style, so here's option 2:
2. Create a new style based on `Normal`, to be used after lists, and set its "Before" spacing as desired. You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to this style to help you apply it quickly whenever you have a body text paragraph right after a list. If you later make formatting changes to the Normal style, the "Normal after a list" style will inherit them.

Comment: This did occur to me. It seems like a drastic measure to take just to make a list look good. Adding "before" spacing to the Normal style will have repercussions all over the document.

Comment: You're right, I updated my answer above.